# How can I set the RecordCount, TOP and NOLOCK with LINQ?

Tags: linq-to-sql

Is it possible to write a select statement that also has `NOLOCK` and `TOP` in LINQ?

What about setting `RowCount` before the query?

Answer (score 2):

Adding .Take(5) to your query is the same as Top 5

Adding .Skip(5) will start returning results on row 6

Not sure how you would add a NOLOCK to a query.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good article dealing with `TransactionScope`:

http://www.madprops.org/blog/linq-to-sql-and-nolock-hints/

Answer (score 1):

TGnat notes how to do `TOP` (via `.Take(n)`). However, there is no inbuilt way of adding granular hints (etc) like `(NOLOCK)` to specific tables. There are a few ways of getting around this:

- write a stored procedure and expose it via the data-context
- write a udf and expose it via the data-context
- use [`ExecuteQuery`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.executequery.aspx) with (parameterized) TSQL that has a `NOLOCK`

Of the 3, the UDF would get my vote:

- it doesn't leave you with literal queries in the C#
- the metadata is strongly defined
- it is composable (with `.Skip`/`.Take`/`.Where` etc)

Comment: 4th option: settings the isolation level to "read uncommited" through either TransactionScope or directly on the DataContext's connection.

Comment: @Lucas - that isn't very granular